# How can I assign a KMS key to a docker container

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I want to use server side Encryption using KMS on my S3 bucket. But instead of using a single KMS key, I want a KMS key for individual docker containers

Not really sure what to try

Answer (score 0):

Buckets are free so you can just create more buckets each with its own key.

If you really want to have multiple keys the client needs to [be aware of what key you want it to use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax) and you can see here on how to modify which key you want. I would avoid this as you then will need to have bucket policy to specify which key should be allowed to be used where.